# Making Multiple Rows into Multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

consider the following table

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
PRODID                                             NUMBER
PRODNAME                                           VARCHAR2(50)

 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 PRODID                                             NUMBER
 PROPID                                             NUMBER
 PRONAME                                            VARCHAR2(100)
 PROVALUE                                           VARCHAR2(100)
```

The Sample data are as follows

```
 select * from prodmas;
    PRODID PRODNAME
---------- --------------
       101 Surf
       102 Ariel
 select * from prodprop
 /

PRODID     PROPID PRONAME   PROVALUE                     
------ ---------- -----------------------------------------------
   101       1001 Price     100
   101       1002 color     Blue
   101       1003 Agent     AV
   102       1001 Price     95
   102       1002 Color     Orange
.....
```

A Normal join query like this

```
 select prodname,provalue
 from prodmas pm
 inner join prodprop pp
 on pm.prodid = pp.prodid
 /
PRODNAME                                           PROVALUE
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
Surf                                               100
Surf                                               Blue
Surf                                               AV
Ariel                                              95
Ariel                                              Orange
```

But the expected output should be like this

```
Surf    100   Blue   AV 
Ariel    95   Orange AV
.......
```

Hope iam clearer

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.ProdID,
        a.ProdName,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProName = 'Price' THEN b.ProValue ELSE NULL END) Price,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProName = 'Color' THEN b.ProValue ELSE NULL END) Color,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProName = 'Agent' THEN b.ProValue ELSE NULL END) Agent
FROM    prodmas a
        LEFT JOIN prodprop b
            ON .prodID = b.prodID
GROUP   BY a.ProdID, a.ProdName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2798a/1)

If you have *unknown* number of value for `PRONAME`, a Dynamic SQL is much preferred so there will be no other alterations required on the query.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(case when PRONAME = ''',
      PRONAME,
      ''' then PROVALUE end) AS ',
      PRONAME
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM prodprop;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   a.ProdID,
                            a.ProdName, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM    prodmas a
                          LEFT JOIN prodprop b
                              ON a.prodID = b.prodID
                  GROUP   BY a.ProdID, a.ProdName');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/879e0/4)

THE OUTPUT from the queries above are the same:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ PRODID ║ PRODNAME ║ PRICE ║ COLOR  ║ AGENT  ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════╬════════╬════════╣
║    101 ║ Surf     ║   100 ║ Blue   ║ AV     ║
║    102 ║ Ariel    ║    95 ║ Orange ║ (null) ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Comment: let me test this in my original scenario

Comment: Wow, you really deserve more than 3 upvotes - this is a great solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

If you are ok specifying everything statically, you can do this with a join on `prodprop` for each property you want to retrieve:

```
SELECT p.prodname, 
    prop1001.provalue AS Price, 
    prop1002.provalue AS Color, 
    prop1003.provalue AS Agent
FROM prodmas p
LEFT OUTER JOIN prodprop prop1001 ON p.prodid = prop1001.prodid 
    AND prop1001.propid=1001
LEFT OUTER JOIN prodprop prop1002 ON p.prodid = prop1002.prodid
    AND prop1002.propid=1002
LEFT OUTER JOIN prodprop prop1003 ON p.prodid = prop1003.prodid
    AND prop1003.propid=1003
```

Otherwise, you are going to have to resort to dynamic SQL to create a custom query, or return the properties table as is, and do the formatting in the front end.

Comment: There are many such properties in the original scenario, will it not hamper the performances....